# What policies are required when using hadoop command with S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to copy the data in on-pre to S3.

I tried to use the following command for that.

```sh
hadoop fs -Dfs.s3a.access.key=******* -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=******* -cp -f hdfs://on-pre/cluster/mydata/dt=20200601/ s3a://some-bucket/somewhere/
```

When I run this command, I get the following error (The path are all fakes):

```
cp: s3a://some-bucket/somewhere/dt=20200601/000000_0.gz: getFileStatus on s3a://some-bucket/somewhere/dt=20200601/000000_0.gz: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxx), S3 Extended Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I set S3 policies following.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9999999999:user/john"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/somewhere/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9999999999:user/john"
            },
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "somewhere/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What S3 policy should I set to use `hadoop fs cp`?

Comment: Sorry, I had an answer which pointed at the normative machine-generated list of permissions, the one which the S3A connector generates which is tested as part of the S3A integration suites and updated in the hadoop s3a docs. But it was deleted. Rather than paste in a copy which will rot due to lack of maintenance, I'll leave you search hadoop.apache.org for it. 

Steve Loughran, Apache Hadoop S3A dev team, author of the S3A IAM rule generation code.

Comment: Even though it's a rotten link, it's helped me. Thank you.

Comment: happy. And remember: it is correct. Taking this up with Meta SO as its +the same as its like not linking to an RFC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListBucket was needed for the subdirectory itself

**The necessary permissions may change as noted in the comments.**

However, here's the code that solved it for your reference

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9999999999:user/john"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/somewhere/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9999999999:user/john"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "somewhere",
                        "somewhere/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9999999999:user/john"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

*Note* This IAM declaration worked on June 5 2020 with Hadoop 3.2.1 or earlier. Future Hadoop releases may change the rules as they or AWS change the connector's or S3's capabilities respectively.

Comment: you probably need GET on the user/ path too, in case someone adds a directory marker there. As of June 2020 I'm working on stopping removing them for better performance especially on versioned buckets, and reduced throttling. But there may be surprises...